# md5sum error when trying to run on text file

Tags: linux, bash, sort, hashsum

I'm trying to run a simple md5sum algorithm, given that I was getting problems before I decided to change my TMP file to a local directory that has enough allocated space (export TMP=some/local/directory. I'm now getting a separate error even after changing the TMP file one more time:

**Error:**

```
-bash: md5sum/dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

**Bash Command:**

```
-bash-4.2$ md5sum<(sort ./directory/text_file.fastq)
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a space after `md5sum`. The `<(...)` construct creates a temporary file, in your case `/dev/fd/63`, and is substitued by the name of that file. Without the space, the temp file name is "glued" directly to `md5sum`, hence the error.

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution): "The process list is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename. **This filename is passed as an argument to the current command** as the result of the expansion".

But this appears overly complicated to me. Why not `sort ./directory/text_file.fastq | md5sum`?

Comment: seems like an easier approach for sure, and will also take less memory on my system I believe. Can I do the following for example with diff? diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)

Comment: It won’t make any noticeable difference to memory usage. You can do this with `diff`, but only with one of its inputs, which makes the overall command harder to read IMO: `sort file1 | diff - <(sort file2)`.